# Ler a tecla ESC em tempo de execução

Tags: c++

Estou escrevendo um programa que lê um número indefinido de valores do teclado e para apenas quando o usuário aperta <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Eu tentei resolver isso usando a função `GetAsyncKeyState()` da seguinte forma.

```
#include <Windows.h>
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)){
        for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
                cout<<v[i]<<endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Mas mesmo depois de apertar <kbd>Esc</kbd> o programa só vai para o `for` após eu inserir algum outro número.
Como faz para o programa pular para o `for` logo após eu apertar <kbd>Esc</kbd>?

Comment: Tá faltando um `}` aí.

Comment: Eu acredito que o seu programa está parando em um outro loop que só sai quando você aperta um número. A chamada `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE)` *sempre* vai retornar diferente de zero caso o ESC esteja pressionado. Sugiro isolar o código falho ou postar o seu código inteiro aqui no SO.

Answer (score 1):

A função GetAsyncKeyState retorna 0 caso não seja pressionada a tecla esc e retorna -32767{acho que é esse valor) quando a tecla esc é pressionada ' então acho que se você colocar assim deve funcionar e acho também que você deve colocar isso dentro de um loop' tipo o while para que ele fique monitorando quando a tecla é apertada ou não.

```
 if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) == -32768)
   {
       for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
       {
           cout<<v[i]<<endl;
       }
           return 0;
   }
```

É por isso que quando você aperta qualquer outra tecla ele entra no loop for,  pois a função GetAsyncKeyState ficara sempre dando como 0, por isso tem que dizer a ela o ' pode ate de repente colocar !=0. acho que funciona também